# dojo version upgrade issues

Tags: javascript, dojo

we currently have dojo library version 1.4.2.
Since, dojo 1.7 is available and we wanted to undertake the upgrade of version.

I simply replaced all files in the library location "my-js-files/dojo1.4.2/*" with folders from the 1.7 version.

most of the root folder structures are same (like dijit, dojo and dojox etc.).

However, I keep facing the following error in my browser (IE8):

> 'dojox.collections.Dictionary' is null or not an object

due to the following line:

```
var myGlobalVariables = new dojox.collections.Dictionary();
```

Has anybody faced this problem? This works just fine without any complaints in dojo 1.4.2.

I have verified that I do have a file as such:
dojo_1.4.3_v1\dojox\collections\Dictionary.js

Is there a compatibility problem between dojo 1.4 and 1.7?
Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: The dojox.collections 1.4 [README](http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/branches/1.4/dojox/collections/README) has _Project state: production_ so it should be compatible. I'd start by checking the `dojo.require` dependencies.

Comment: @McDowell thanks for the input. Yes, adding the dojo.require(dojox.collections.Dictionary) indeed solved the problem. But I am getting similar errors in many other places. My point is I did not need the declaration when I was using the dojo 1.4.2 version. That kind of throws me off a little bit. also the current code base is too huge to go and change this in all places. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Aysuman - This is probably a load ordering bug hidden by the way the 1.4 implementation worked. If you intend to keep using `dojo.require` instead of switching to the new AMD mechanism, I guess you could try creating a script loaded before other dependencies with a bunch of `dojo.require` calls. However, you are just hiding missing dependency bugs in your code and this will not help you in the long run. If you have dependencies on `dojox` packages that were marked as _experimental_ or _beta_ in 1.4, there may just be breaking changes that you will have to fix.

Comment: IMHO its the wrong approach to fix your own codebase if it indeed is that big. Instead let the monkey test against 1.7 in your sandbox and figure out which dependencies are giving you a hazzle. Each of those bugs would most likely have a bug report or would be easily fixed with (often is) slight modifications to the dependency code. For instance, hidden, private modules breaks AMD pattern if those 'private' hidden modules are used in other files then in the one it is declared by. I've found myself making new dojox/widget/_hiddenModuleName.js file and adding it to respective define-dependencies